# Is plotly express timeline down?

Tags: python, plotly, typeerror, streamlit

I can't make plots on streamlit using the px.timeline, even using their basic dummy data this is always returning

> TypeError: Object of type timedelta is not JSON serializable

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Any idea how to get through this? I couldn't find documentation or reported bug on this